# Who is throwing (and catching) this MySQL Exception?

Tags: python, mysql, django, exception

i'm using Python with MySQL and Django.  I keep seeing this error and I can't figure out where the exception is being thrown:

> `Exception _mysql_exceptions.ProgrammingError: (2014, "Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now") in <bound method Cursor.__del__ of <MySQLdb.cursors.Cursor object at 0x20108150>> ignored`

I have many "try" and "exception" blocks in my code--if the exception occurred within one of those, then I would see my own debugging messages.  The above Exception is obviously being caught somewhere since my program does not abort when the Exception is thrown.

I'm very puzzled, can someone help me out?

Answer (score 8):

I had exactly that error (using MySQLdb and Django) and discovered that the reason it was "ignored" was that it occurred in a `__del__` method. Exceptions in `__del__` are categorically ignored:
[`object.__del__` datamodel](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#object.__del__)

There doesn't seem to be any way to catch it from further up the stack (at least according to [this thread](http://python.6.n6.nabble.com/debugging-ignored-exceptions-at-cleanup-td1516842.html)), but you can edit MySQLdb/cursors.py or monkey-patch to get your own `__del__` in there that catches the exception and drops you into a pdb prompt or logs a full traceback.

Comment: Were you ever able to determine the specific code that was ultimately causing the error for you?  I'm wondering if there's a specific problem with use of mysql inside Django, a common module, or my code in particular.

Comment: The root problem was totally my fault (sharing a db connection between threads), and the exception happens when closing the connection, in trying to flush a result set. Django's only blame in the matter was in, as usual, making it impossible to debug when anything remotely unexpected happens.

Comment: Dude you're a lifesaver. I was getting this error because I had a DROP TABLE statement before creating a table and I lost my mind trying to debug it, I had no threading over the same conn, nothing.

Answer (score 3):

This is a Python Error.

See: http://eric.lubow.org/2009/python/pythons-mysqldb-2014-error-commands-out-of-sync/

It looks like there is a problem with your MySQLdb Query.

Comment: thanks for the link.  I don't use any explicit MySQL queries or use any cursor objects.  All the queries I do go through Django objects.  One big problem for me is not being able to see where this exception is being thrown.

Comment: Resuming: As in php, you can not open a second mysql´s connection without to close teh first one !

Answer (score 2):

I believe this error can occur if you are using the same connection/cursor from multiple threads. 
However, I dont think the creators of Django has made such a mistake, but if you are doing something by yourself it can easily happen.

Comment: I have no multithreading in my program, also only one instance of my program is running.  I should be the only one accessing the database when my program is running.  Are there any debugging techniques to see where the exception is thrown?  I have my program set to run over a large set data.  If I only test a small subset of data, everything is ok.  But when I set it off to run on the entire set, this MySQL exception appears...  Right now, I'm running the whole set and piping both standard in and standard error to see if I can get a better idea of where the problem is showing up.

Answer (score 2):

After printing out a bunch of stuff and debugging, I figured out the problem I think.  One of the libraries that I used didn't close the connection or the cursor.  But this problem only shows up if I iterate through a large amount of data.  The problem is also very intermittent and I still don't know who's throwing the "command out of sync" exception.  But now that we closed both the connection and cursor, I don't see the errors anymore.

Answer (score 0):

The exceptions in object destructors (`__del__`) are ignored, which this message indicates. If you execute some MySQL command without fetching results from the cursor (e.g. 'create procedure' or 'insert') then the exception is unnoticed until the cursor is destroyed.
If you want to raise and catch an exception, call explicitly `cursor.close()` somewhere before going out of the scope.